# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\sinh\sqrt{2s}}$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}}$ (related to Brownian motion)

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, laplace-transform

I was reading "2018The computation of the probability density and distribution functions for some families of random variables by means of the Wynn-p accelerated Post-Widder formula" and run into the following question.

The paper gives two Laplace transforms:
$$L_{X_S}(s)=\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\sinh\sqrt{2s}}\ \text{and} \ L_{X_C}(s)=\frac{1}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}},$$

where $X_S$ and $X_C$ can be interpreted as the hitting time of a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. The paper also says that the densities are:

$$f_{X_S}(x)=\pi^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}k^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}k^2\pi^2x}\ \text{and} \ f_{X_C}(s)=\pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{2}(k+\frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2x}.$$

I am interested in the density functions, i.e., the inverse of Laplace transforms. There is one way in "2001Probability laws related to the Jacobi theta and Riemann zeta functions, and Brownian excursions", through $L_{X_C}$. However, that paper mentions reciprocal property between $X_C$ and $X_C$ and between $X_S$ and $X_C$, which I do not understand.

In particular, since $\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{1}{s+a}$ for $a>0$, directly applying Laplace transform to densities may lead to divergent series, e.g., $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{k^2 \pi^2 }{s+\frac{1}{2}k^2\pi^2}$. A similar expression $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+b^2}=\frac{\pi}{b}\coth\pi b$ is also noticed, but I cannot see how to apply it so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The inverse Laplace Transform, $f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)\right\}$ with $F(s)=1/\cosh(\sqrt{2s})$, is given by the Bromwich integral
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\frac1{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{2 s})}e^{st}\,ds
\end{align}
$F(s)$ has simple poles at $s_n=-\frac{1}{2}(n+\frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2$.
With the residue theorem we can write
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{2 s})}e^{st}, s=s_n\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lim_{s\to s_n}\left((s- s_n)\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{2 s})}e^{st}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{2 s_n}}{\sinh(\sqrt{2 s_n})}e^{s_n t}
\end{align}
where I used l'Hôpital's rule. With $\sinh(\sqrt{2 s_n})=i\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi)=i(-1)^n$ we now find
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) e^{s_n t}\\
&=\pi \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \exp{\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2 t\right]}
\end{align}
which is equal to the stated result.

Likewise,
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\sinh(\sqrt{2s})}\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\sinh(\sqrt{2s})}e^{st}, s=-\frac{1}{2}n^2\pi^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{s\to -n^2\pi^2/2}\left((s+n^2\pi^2/2)\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\sinh(\sqrt{2s})}e^{st}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{\cosh(\sqrt{-n^2\pi^2})} \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}n^2\pi^2 t\right)}\\
&=\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^2 \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}n^2\pi^2 t\right)}\\
&=\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^2 \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}n^2\pi^2 t\right)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for that. Beautiful. I think your extra factor 2 comes from the residuce theorem. Consider we need to close the contour to apply the residue theorem, then n shall start from 0 to infinity, i.e., closing the contour to the right hand side of the real axis, or negative infinity to 0, i.e., closing the contour to the left hand side of the real axis. Same reasoning to the Mellin Barnes integral. So it shall not be n from negative infinity to positive infinity. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your statement, but I think you're right that I should just start the sum from $n=0$. I think the point is that by letting the sum run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, I'm counting each pole twice.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-030-20524-9%2F1.pdf
Here is a quick reference, in which we are tying to separate the poles. I am not sure neither since this depends on the value of c, which may further affect the poles shall be included in the summation.